# Calculating the right dominant eigenvector of a nth degree matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am working with a generalized Leslie matrix $A$ and am wondering: is it possible to use Mathematica to calculate the right dominant eigenvector of $A$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix?

Below is my code used to calculate the dominant eigenvector of the $2 \times 2$ version of $A$.

```
(*Conditions: a1>0, a2>0, 0<b1<=1*)

A={{a1,a2},{b1,0}};
Eigenvectors[A,1]
```

I am not sure how to use Mathematica to calculate the right dominant eigenvector, nor do I know how to work with an $n$ dimensional matrix, as opposed to the special case of $2 \times 2$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear[m, a, b];
m[n_] := 
 SparseArray[{{1, j_} -> a[j], {i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 -> 
    b[i - 1]}, {n, n}]
m[5] // MatrixForm
Eigenvectors[m[5], 1]
```

[image]